# Line to polygon in Oracle Spatial

Tags: polygon, sql, linestring, oracle-spatial

I have a table that contains buildings in a line geometry where a line starts and ends at the same point. Is there away to convert lines to polygons in Oracle Spatial?

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer or is my proposed solution not sufficient for your needs?

Comment: @Lars I am so sorry for not replying to you earlier because I did not have the time to test your solution. I have now tested the "UPDATE - Better solution" version and it worked like a charm! Thank you very much for your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works for linestrings with not too much vertices (which should be the case for most buildings):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION line_to_polygon (closedLineGeom SDO_GEOMETRY) 
RETURN SDO_GEOMETRY
AS
    wktStringLine VARCHAR2(4000);
    wktStringPolygon VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
    wktStringLine := SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(closedLineGeom);
    wktStringPolygon := replace(wktStringLine, 'LINESTRING (', 'POLYGON ((');
    wktStringPolygon := wktStringPolygon || ')';
    RETURN SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY(wktStringPolygon);
END;
```

The function just replaces the linestring WKT (`SDO_UTIL.FROM_WKTGEOMETRY`) with polygon WKT and returns it as a geometry (`SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY`). Note that this function will break for linestrings with a lot of vertices because the length of a VARCHAR2 is limited to 4000. Also you have to make sure that the line is really closed!

**UPDATE  - Better solution**

The following is a better solution that does not have the previous limitation:

```
UPDATE your_table_name x
SET 
x.geometry_column_name.SDO_GTYPE = 2003,
x.geometry_column_name.SDO_ELEM_INFO = SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,1);
```

Of course you still have to make sure that your linestrings are really closed!